# Why i could not able to set the background of my installer?

Tags: nsis

I am writing a script for my installer and  i want to set a   background image for it.So iam using this code but it is not working.

code:

```
  !define UMUI_USE_CUSTOMBG
!macro UMUI_BG
        SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
        File "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\BGSkins\SoftGray\BackGround.bmp"
        BgImage::SetBg /NOUNLOAD /FILLSCREEN "$PLUGINSDIR\BackGround.bmp"
        CreateFont $1 "Verdana" 30 700
        BgImage::AddText /NOUNLOAD "$(^Name)" $1 255 255 255 16 114 -1 -1
        BgImage::AddText /NOUNLOAD "$(^Name)" $1 132 132 132 12 110 -1 -1
        BgImage::Redraw /NOUNLOAD
!macroend
!macro UMUI_BG_Destroy
        BgImage::Destroy
!macroend
```

Comment: Which image? The .exe icon?

Comment: !insertmacro MUI_DEFAULT UMUI_PAGEBGIMAGE_BMP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\Skins\gray\PageBG2.bmp" here i want to set background image but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, UMUI_PAGEBGIMAGE_BMP is not a UMUI setting. You should read the [documentation](http://ultramodernui.sourceforge.net/Readme.php) to find the available settings (and look at the examples).

Comment: I have changed code please look at it .I have replaced it as per the documentation

Comment: !define UMUI_USE_BG "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UltraModernUI\BGSkins\SoftGray\BackGround.bmp" tghis i have used to get the already defined bgskin

Comment: This is setting the whole background .But i want to set only installer page background